# How to handle an unlock screen event in c# for windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, unlock

Please explain in code how to handle unlock screen event for 8.1 app. i actually want to read next line from a text file and display it on my notification area every time my screen is unlocked.please explain in detail as i am new to c#.

where to write this code in MainPage.xaml.cs ?!

```
PhoneApplicationFrame rootFrame = (Application.Current as App).RootFrame;
rootFrame.Obscured += OnObscured;
rootFrame.Unobscured += Unobscured;
void OnObscured(Object sender, ObscuredEventArgs e)
{

}
void Unobscured(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please take a moment and read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Questions asking us to give you an answer without any **code example** of what you tried is off topic.

Comment: @ErikPhilips have a look now

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see I can conclude that this this code:

```
PhoneApplicationFrame rootFrame = (Application.Current as App).RootFrame;
rootFrame.Obscured += OnObscured;
rootFrame.Unobscured += Unobscured;
```

should be put into constructor of you `App` class(in `App.cs` file), so eventually it will look like:

```
public class App
{
    // more code could be here

    public App()
    {
         PhoneApplicationFrame rootFrame = (Application.Current as App).RootFrame;
         rootFrame.Obscured += OnObscured;
         rootFrame.Unobscured += Unobscured;
    }

    // and some code could be here

    void OnObscured(Object sender, ObscuredEventArgs e)
    {    
    }

    void Unobscured(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
    }     

    // and even here
}
```

p.s./offtop/ general advice: if you're new to c# then it would make more sense to learn c# first and only then dive into winphone/asp/desktop/etc development. That's what my personal experience tells me.

hope this helps

Comment: i am writing that code in public app() constructor ... but the following line is showing error.... " PhoneApplicationFrame rootframe =(Application.Current as App).RootFrame;.........ERROR-Member 'LockScreenNotification.App.RootFrame.get' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify with an type name;

Comment: 1. please post all code 2. learn c# basics, I doubt that any significant progress is possible without that